Git LFS - migrate import/export round-trip
I'm migrating my Git hosting from a host that supports large files (AWS CodeCommit) to a host that requires LFS (GitHub). I've set up a job that periodically migrates code by cloning it down from AWS, running git lfs migrate import --everything --above=50MB, then pushing into GitHub. Luckily, this seems to be idempotent, so every time I do this I get the same rewritten SHA1 hashes in GitHub.
Once I get my team moved over to using GitHub primarily for development, I'd like to reverse the migration script so it clones from GitHub, does some invocation of git lfs migrate export, then pushes to AWS; this would be so we can temporarily support our existing CI/CD pipelines. However, I'd really love it the git lfs migrate export invocation would result in my original, pre-migration commit SHAs.
If that's not possible, I'll just live with it.

Edit: to clarify, migrate export is similarly idempotent, but the rewrite doesn't remove .gitattributes, which is maybe what causes the SHAs to not match at the end.
